# need to add a variable to the end of img src

Tags: jquery

I have the following tracking pixel:

```
<img id="pixel" alt="" width="1" height="1" src="https://domain.com/file.cfm?amount={tag_amount}&amp;tracking={tag_invoicenumber}&amp;transtype=sale&amp;merchantID=29562" />
```

I need to add a variable to the end of the image source. Here's the jQuery I'm playing with.

```
$('img#pixel [src]').append(affiliateCode);
```

It's not working. Any suggestions?? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Append is for full DOM objects only, you want to append to the src attribute.

Try:

```
var affiliateCode = '12345';

$('#pixel').attr('src', $('#pixel').attr('src') + '&affiliate=' + affiliateCode);
```

Obviously changing the parameter name to whatever you need.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks. I dropped the '&affiliate='. Didn't need that piece.

Comment: Quite alright, I would suggest using John Hartsock's modification to make $('#pixel') a variable and reusing that, as that is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
var affiliateCode = "affiliateCode=1234";
var myimage = $('img#pixel');
myimage.attr("src", myimage.attr("src") + "&" + affiliateCode);
```

if the affiliate code is static this is more efficient

```
$('img#pixel').attr("src",function (index, attribute) {
  attribute += "&affiliateCode=1234";
});
```

Comment: This is slightly better than mine from an efficiency point of view, as binding the jQuery object to a variable rather than repeating the selector twice results in Sizzle only needing to be used once, a single object instatiation.

Comment: @orbling ... @mmsa...Actually; if the affiliate code is static then this is more efficient.

Comment: Yes, totally forgot that attr() had an attr(string, function) variation.  Very neat. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it so:

```
var srcVal = $('img#pixel').attr('src');
$('img#pixel').attr('src', srcVal + affiliateCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#pixel').attr('src', $('#pixel').attr('src')+'&affiliateCode='affiliateCode );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the above code:

```
var affiliateCode = '12345';
$('#pixel').attr('src', $('#pixel').attr('src') + '&affiliate=' + affiliateCode);
```

was enterd correctly but stackoverflow's editor does strange things with code.
the parameter `&affiliate` should contain an ampersand followed by `amp` and a semicolon.